# Scheduling 5 working days with at least 1 holiday at the weekend

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

A cashier wants to work five days a week, but he wants to have at least one of Saturday and Sunday off. In how many ways can he choose the days he will work?

It's clear that there are $21$ choices of $5$ days in all. It's also clear that I need to subtract number of choices with $2$ holidays, the answer in the book *A Walk through Combinatorics* says that there are $\binom{5}{3} = 10$ such, but I don't understand why it is so. Why taking exactly $2$ holidays equals $\binom{5}{3} = 10$  or $\binom{5}{2} = 10$?

Comment: If you work both Saturday and Sunday then you need to choose $3$ out of the $5$ weekdays to reach a total of $5$.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of ways the cashier can select exactly $k$ weekend days and $5 - k$ weekdays to work is
$$\binom{2}{k}\binom{5}{5 - k}$$

**Method 1:**  Direct count.

To have at least one weekend holiday, the cashier must either work all five weekdays or work one weekend day and four weekdays.

The cashier can work all five weekdays in $\binom{2}{0}\binom{5}{5}$ ways.  The cashier can work one weekend day and four weekdays in $\binom{2}{1}\binom{5}{4}$ ways.  Hence, the number of schedules that permit the cashier to have at least one weekend holiday is
$$\binom{2}{0}\binom{5}{5} + \binom{2}{1}\binom{5}{4}$$

**Method 2:** Complementary counting.

There are $\binom{7}{5}$ ways to select five workdays during the week without restriction.  As lulu observed in the comments, if the cashier were to work both days at the weekend, then the cashier would also have to work on three weekdays, which can be done in $\binom{2}{2}\binom{5}{3}$ ways.  Hence, the number of ways the cashier can work five days with at least one weekend holiday is
$$\binom{7}{5} - \binom{2}{2}\binom{5}{3}$$